# playing video in ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, video

I have a video, and I need to play it in my ASP.NET page's home page, it should play in a customized small area whenever that home page gets loaded. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which video is it flash or html5?Please be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's `HTML5` convert it to `ogg,mp4,WebM` and then upload it to your server then it would be easier and you can do it this way:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="yourmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="yourmovie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

EDIT:

Actually there are tons of samples on the web. Here are some of them.

http://www.aspnet-video.com/aspnetvideo_Demonstration-PlayList-Presentation.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/CsharpWebVideo04212007133218PM/CsharpWebVideo.aspx

http://videoplayer.codeplex.com/

Comment: you're welcome,and I have updated with HTML5 too you can try that which is more easier way to implement a video.

Comment: thanks DotNetter, I think its not HTML5, however I'll try and let you know

Comment: Ok.If you have any prob let me know.

Comment: I dont understand the example in that link u provided.......I've worked with silverlight, in that we can directly display the video right, is it not possible in simple asp.net

Comment: if you give some coding or demo samples it will be really helpful...am also searching for that

Comment: Above provided some samples where you can start with.As you said we can do in silverlight but not with normal Asp.Net application.

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread4468-media-player-on-a-aspnet-web-form.aspx i just followed this link.......its working for me, but I dont like the controls to be displayed, only the video is enough....what can I do

Comment: http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html I got the solution from here, thanks DotNetter for ur guidance....thanks alot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9713/discussion-between-shanish-and-dotnetter)